# Get Xcode console output to log in a file

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoa

I'm running some iOS app tests and would like to get xcode's console to log its output to a file. 
Is there a way I can do this?

Answer (score 0):

There is a wonderful framework that will do this (and other logging methods) for you.  It's called [CocoaLumberjack](https://github.com/robbiehanson/CocoaLumberjack/wiki/GettingStarted)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Redirecting debug output from XCode 4 console to a log file.](http://pastebin.com/aymnb9ce)

```
defaults write com.apple.Xcode PBXGDBDebuggerLogToFile YES
defaults write com.apple.Xcode PBXGDBDebuggerLogFileName <filepath>

/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/libexec/gdb/gdb-arm-apple-darwin

#!/bin/sh

/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/libexec/gdb/gdb-arm-apple-darwin- $* | tee -a $HOME/tmp/xcode-gdb.log 2>&1
```

Comment: @Berik there is an alternative solution ?

Answer (score -1):

Try this instead in mac terminal

check name of the device from About Section

`sudo log collect --deviceName "NAME" --last 10m --output iphone_test1.logarchive`